# GVim code folding has different text depending on how I open the file

Tags: vim, folding, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am using GVim on Windows and I typically use AsciiDoc text files for writing. I also have the vim-asciidoctor plugin loaded.

If I right-click a file and open it with GVim, the text on the folded line is:

```
+-- 6 lines: == Saving files------------------------------------
```

If I open GVim from the Windows start menu and then use `:e Documents/myfiles/notes/<filename>` to open the file, the text on the folded line is:

```
== [00.5%] Saving files [5/950 lines]---------------------------
```

**Why is the text format different?**

I prefer the first version and would like to have that version no matter how I open the file.

Comment: The first style is Vim's default style, which is expected when you use that plugin. The second style is added by another plugin or something in your config file. Comparing the output of `:scriptnames` in each scenario could help. If unsure, add them to your question so that we can take a look.

Comment: Thanks @romainl. I also had a plugin called vim-asciidoc-folding which I had tried before discovering vim-asciidoctor. When I remove that plugin, I get the default text no matter how I load the file.